# Earliest documentation of kissing

Tags: history, kissing

What are the earliest sources you know of that mention kissing (be it romantic, familial, kissing mezuzos/tefillin/torah etc.)? There are obvious tznius issues when it comes to people kissing other people, so perhaps that is a separate question.

I ask because it would appear that kissing may not be an originally Jewish invention. There is (secular) documentation that many non-Jewish groups practiced kissing, both romantic and otherwise going back approximately three thousand years, at least in Europe, the Middle East and South Asia.

Comment: Whoever thought that kissing was a Jewish invention?

Comment: One might think that because there is potentially ritual significance to kissing (viz. because some people are noheg to kiss various ritual objects) that it must be an ancient Jewish practice.

Comment: Agriculture was also an ancient Jewish practice, but it was certainly not invented by Jews.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Brashis 27:27 is the earliest source in the Torah of kissing. This was when Yaakov kissed Yitzchok prior to the Brachos.

ויגש וישק לו וירח את ריח בגדיו ויברכהו ויאמר ראה ריח בני כריח שדה אשר ברכו יהוה

Comment: Doesn't get much older than that. Thanks!

Comment: Wait... Yaakov kissed Yitzchak? I always thought this meant Yitzchak kissed Yaakov.

Comment: @jake It is unclear, because ויגש clearly has Yaakov as the subject, while וירח has Yitzchak as the subject. The trop indicated a hard pause (zakef) on לו so it would seem from that that Yaakov is doing the kissing.

Comment: @DoubleAA, Now that I look at it inside, it seems pretty obvious that Yaakov is kissing Yitzchak, as per the previous verse: "וַיֹּאמֶר אֵלָיו יִצְחָק אָבִיו גְּשָׁה-נָּא וּשְׁקָה-לִּי בְּנִי".